# Deleting a column from echelon form of a matrix is still in echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, gaussian-elimination

This is a true or false question which demands a counter-example in case it's false. The question says:

> If we delete *any* column of a matrix in echelon form, it will still
>   remain in echleon form.

**My attempt**:
Not necessarily. I took the example:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \fbox{1} & 2 & 3 & 0\\
    0 & \fbox{4} & 7 & 6\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \fbox{9} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
If we delete the first column, the matrix becomes:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 0\\
    4 & 7 & 6\\
    0 & 0 & 9\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
which doesn't appear to be in echleon form anymore according to me.

But my textbook says it's a true statement. I am not getting where am i going wrong.

**EDIT**

The definition of echleon form of a matrix as it appears in my textbook:
[image]

Comment: @MatthewTowers I added the definition for reference. Though I am sure it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your textbook is just wrong. For a more simple example, consider deleting any column but the last from the identity matrix $I_n$: the resulting matrix will have a zero row that is not at the end, so will not be in echelon form, unless your textbook is using some non-standard definition of "echelon form".

Comment: It's a supplementary problem of Schaum's outlines Linear Algebra and uses the standard definition of echleon form. It must be a typo. Thank you for confirming.